# error configuring proxy pass for upstream app

Tags: nginx

I have an application running as a docker container mapped to port 8080; On this same server I also have nginx also configured to serve a Laravel application which has some URLs that have `api` at context root `https://example.com/api/news` for example. The docker application URLs starts with either `web/` or `api/` so to avoid URL proxy confusions I'm trying to serve all docker container application `/comments` context path, thereby Laravel requests continue from `host/api` and docker app URL `host/comments/api` etc. I have following locations in the configuration (in the order described here)

```
upstream remark42 {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080 weight=100 max_fails=5 fail_timeout=5;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    access_log /var/www/example.com/storage/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/example.com/storage/logs/error.log;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example_com_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example_com.key;

    root /var/www/example.com/public/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass    unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   APP_ENV  production;
        include         fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /comments {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        rewrite ^/comments(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://remark42/;
    }

    location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
        access_log        on;
        etag              on;
        if_modified_since exact;
        add_header Pragma "public";
        add_header        Cache-Control "max-age=31557600, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }
```

And then at the end of file

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

I get a 404 error on accessing `https://www.example.com/comments/web/embed.js` or `https://www.example.com/comments/api/v1/user?blah`

with the JS file giving following error in logs

```
2020/05/18 18:05:54 [error] 3047#3047: *5035 open() "/var/www/example.com/public/comments/web/last-comments.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 49.207.48.221, server: , request: "GET /comments/web/last-comments.js HTTP/2.0", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/blogs/yet-another-svn-change-log-tool"
```

So the proxy pass doesn't work and it tries to fetch js files from disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are two solutions to your problem.

```
location ^~ /comments/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_pass http://remark42/;
}
```

or

```
location ^~ /comments {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    rewrite ^/comments(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://remark42;
}
```

To understand, read [nginx proxy module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

The first solution, is based upon

> If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a
>   request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI
>   matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive

Ie. /comments is replaced by /

The second solution is based on

> When the URI is changed inside a proxied location using the rewrite
>   directive, and this same configuration will be used to process a
>   request (break):
>
> ```
> location /name/ {
>     rewrite    /name/([^/]+) /users?name=$1 break;
>     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
> }
> ```
>
> In this case, the URI specified in the directive is ignored and the
>   full changed request URI is passed to the server.

You were passing an URI, the last "/" in "http://remark42/".

Comment: Thanks, Gerard; I tried `/comments/` with `http://remark42/` proxy pass; there's something in the config which still prevents `https://www.example.com/comments/web/embed.js` to match. I've added the `nginx` and `site.conf` here https://gist.github.com/anadimisra/4c286977ebe97a1c4c53be0a3f91b928

Comment: You did restart nginx?

Comment: Can you remove "location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ " to test?

Comment: Yup it works then, but fails for the .html urls `https://www.example.com/comments/web/iframe.html`

Comment: how do I let the `'comments/` URI and `.js` `.html` config of laravel co-exist?

Comment: OK, the reason for your problem is that regular expression locations (eg. "\.(?:css|js)$") take priority on prefix locations (eg. "/comments/"), and the first match in your configuration wins.  Now, there is a construct ("^~"), that says: "with this prefix match, don't search the regex locations".  I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As documented in the [`ngx_http_rewrite_module` documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html), after a rewrite, the `location` is searched again - so after the rewrite the `location ~* \.(?:css|js)$` is entered instead of executing the `proxy_pass`.

If what you want to do is to represent resources from `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` under `http://www.example.com/comments/`, then `proxy_pass` will do this automatically. From the [NGINX Reverse Proxy documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/):

> If the URI is specified along with the address, it replaces the part of the request URI that matches the location parameter.

"URI" here means the part after the upstream name, which you specified as `/`.

So your location should be simply written as such:

```
   location /comments/ {
        proxy_set_header ...;
        proxy_pass http://remark42/;
    }
```

Note the ending `/` on the `location` path to make the mapping canonical - so `https://www.example.com/comments/web/embed.js` is proxied to `http://remark42/web/embed.js` ( `/comments/` is mapped to `/` ).

Otherwise, you'd get something like this: `https://www.example.com/comments/web/embed.js` -> `http://remark42//web/embed.js` - note the double slash. This is often not a problem as the upstream server should handle this and canonicalize the double slash, but it is not correct.

Comment: hey Guss, tried that, it still tries to fetch a file. Here's the configuration, just to know I have other conflicts overriding this block. https://gist.github.com/anadimisra/4c286977ebe97a1c4c53be0a3f91b928

Comment: As @GerardHPile mentioned in the answer you accepted, even after fixing the `/comments` location, the regular expression locations that match the URL suffix will still win over a path based location - so trying to load anything from `/comments` that also matches `.js` will fall to the regex match. USing `^~` for `/comments` fixes that problem as well.